# Get the output and return value from another bash function

Tags: bash, function, callback

In function_two, I need to get both the output from echo and the return value from function_one

```
#!/bin/bash
function_one() {
    echo "okay then"
    return 2
}
function_two() {
    local a_function="function_one"
    local string=`${a_function}`
    echo $string # echos "okay then"
    echo "$?" #echos 0 - how do we get the returned value of 2?
}
function_two
```

When trying `echo "$?"` I get `0` instead of `2`

**Update**

As Ipor Sircer pointed out, `$?` above is giving the exit code of the previous command `echo $string`

So instead I grab the exit code immediately after.  And as choroba mentioned, the localization and assignment of the variable needed to be separated.

Here is the working script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function_one() {
    echo "okay then"
    return 2
}
function_two() {
    local a_function="function_one"
    local string
    string=`${a_function}`
    local exitcode=$?
    echo "string: $string" # okay then
    echo "exitcode: $exitcode" # 2
}
function_two
```

Comment: the `echo $string` command has run successfully, so the exitcode is 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

0 is the exit status of the last command executed, i.e. `echo $string`.

If you need to use the exit status later, store it in a variable:

```
local string
string=`${a_function}`
local status=$?
echo "Output: $string"
echo "Status: $status"
```

You also need to separate the assignment and localization of the variable to not get the status of `local` instead.

Comment: Status is still 0 instead of 2.  Losing the status from function_one since it's executed in a sub process with backtick

Comment: @asdfqwerzxcv: No, it's because you're getting the status of `local`. See the updated answer.